# return array from trait function in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i have a problem , an 
error when  return array or  variable from function..
here is my code:

in **Traits\UserTrait.php**

```
 public function login()
             {
               $errors   = new MessageBag; // initiate MessageBag
               $username = Input::get('email');
               $password = Input::get('password');
              return compact('username', 'password','email');
             }
```

and 
in **UserController.php**

```
       public function __construct(user $model)
        {
         $this->model=$model;

        }
       public function login()
        {
            $this->model->login();
          if(filter_var($username, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $user = User::where('email',$request['email'])->first();
            if($user && $user->email_active != 1)
            {
                $errors = new MessageBag(['email' => [__('auth.emailVerify')]]);
                return Redirect::back()->withErrors($errors)->withInput(Input::except('password'));
            } 
}
}
```

actually in user model, i put  `use UserTrait;`

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: thanks for your replying ..,the error:Undefined variable: username

Comment: Your code is confusing `return compact('username', 'password','email');
` where is email variable in your code?

Comment: i put login(Request $request) , but still have the error !
is compact code is correct?

Comment: what is the error you get when u use $request

Comment: the same error : Undefined variable: username

Answer (score 1):

You might be calling a method that returns something, but you are not actually doing anything with the return at all. (Returning from a method doesn't magically import variables into the callers scope)

```
$this->model->login(); // never assigning the result to anything
```

Ofcourse you are getting undefined `$username` because in `UserController@login` there is no variable named `$username`.

This would at least get that `username` key and assign it to a variable:

```
$data = $this->model->login();
$username = $data['username'];
```

Comment: oh, yes..worked now ..your reply so simple... very thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is not how traits work, they do no magically fill variables that are missing.
On the line

```
if(filter_var($username, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
```

Your are using `$username`, which is not set.